# How to make Mercurial auto-commit on merge without conflicts?

Tags: mercurial

I was surprised when coming back to Mercurial after using Git for quite a few years when I did an `hg pull -u`: Mercurial fetched the new patches, did a merge without conflict, but still asked for a commit.

Is there a way to automatically commit when a `hg pull -u` did not create any conflict?

Currently, the revlog is polluted with many "Merge..." commit messages, and I'd really prefer to not see them (although the merge itself should be kept in history in case the automated process makes the wrong decisions).

Answer (score 2):

Nope, I don't think so. This is a fundamental difference between git and hg. Mercurial wants you to make sure the merge was correct, possibly by running your test suite, before committing.

If you don't like merge commits, maybe you should be rebasing your work instead of merging? It's common practice to keep history linear by rebasing feature branches instead of merging.

If you are rebasing a lot, it helps if you make use of the phase system by pushing WIP work to a non-publishing repository and then once code passes review and gets accepted, it gets rebased and then pushed to a publishing repository. You might also find the evolve extension useful, especially if you are working collaboratively with a team, as that will propagate the history editing operations between developers.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any reference that you like for the rebasing workflow?

Answer (score 0):

you could use an alias for that:

```
alias hg_pull='hg pull -u && hg commit -m "No Merge Conflict"'
```

Running hg_pull from your repo should do more or less what you wish.
If anything goes wrong at "hg pull -u" step, the commit is not triggered.

Let me know if something is unclear!